# How can I binding a value of the ResourceDictionary with IValueConverter in XAML directly?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I wanna bind a value inside a ResourceDictionary which is a Theme.

I followed some tutorial in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/theming

Here is the code of the ResourceDictionary named Black.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Test.Themes.Black">
    <Color x:Key="PrimaryBackground" x:FactoryMethod="FromHex">
        <x:Arguments>
            <x:String>#101010</x:String>
        </x:Arguments>
    </Color>    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Here is the code in App.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Test.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Black.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And here is the ContentView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.Views"
             xmlns:VM="clr-namespace:Test.ViewModels"             
             mc:Ignorable="d"             
             x:Class="Test.Views.MainView">
    <ContentView.BindingContext>
        <VM:MainViewVM></VM:MainViewVM>
    </ContentView.BindingContext>    
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="">            
        </Grid>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Now I want to bind the BackgroundColor property of the Grid above to the value `PrimaryBackground` of the ResourceDictionary.

How can I achieve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `DynamicResource` to set the `BackgroundColor` like following code

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PrimaryBackground}">
            <Label Text="Face-Palm Monkey"
                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                   Margin="15"/>

</Grid>
```

Here is running sceenshot.

[image]

I recommand you set the `ResourceDictionary` directly in `App.xaml` like following format.

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="MVVMWebView.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="PrimaryBackground" x:FactoryMethod="FromHex">
                <x:Arguments>
                    <x:String>#101010</x:String>
                </x:Arguments>
            </Color>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

If you want to use `IValueConverter` ,just add the `Converter` in the `ContentPage.Resources` like follow code. `IValueConverter` used `Converter` tab, you just use `StaticResource`, it does not conflict with `DynamicResource`

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataBindingDemos"
             x:Class="DataBindingDemos.EnableButtonsPage"
             Title="Enable Buttons">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:IntToBoolConverter x:Key="intToBool" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <StackLayout Padding="10, 0">


        <Button Text="Search"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Reference entry1},
                                    Path=Text.Length,
                                    Converter={StaticResource intToBool}}" />
     </StackLayout>
   </ContentPage>
```

==========**Update**==============

I make a convert by your needs. I used `Button` to convert day and night. Here is running GIF.

[image]

```
 <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <controls:ColorBoolConverter x:Key="intToBool" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <StackLayout>

        <Button Text="Submit"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                Command="{Binding ChangeCommand}"
                />

        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Grid BackgroundColor="{Binding IsDark, Converter={StaticResource intToBool}}">
            <Label Text="Face-Palm Monkey"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       Margin="15"
                        />

        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
```

Here is background code about the Layout.

```
  public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = new MyViewModel();
        }
    }
```

Here is Convertor code.

```
    public class ColorBoolConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is bool)
            {
                if ((Boolean)value)
                    return Color.FromHex("#101010");
                else
                    return Color.White;
            }
            return Color.White;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Here is Test `MyViewModel.cs`

```
    public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ICommand ChangeCommand { protected set; get; }
        bool _isDark = false;
        public bool IsDark
        {
            get
            {
                return _isDark;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_isDark != value)
                {
                    _isDark = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("IsDark");

                }
            }

        }




        public MyViewModel()
        {
            ChangeCommand =  new Command(() =>
            {

                IsDark = !IsDark;


            });
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's more, what should I do if I need to use an IValueConverter?

Comment: Li The code for IValueConverter is something different from my project. I am afraid I do not fully know its meaning. I tried to modify the code like this:{Binding Source={x:Reference Test},Path=PrimaryBackground,Converter={StaticResource intToBool}} while it doesn't work but reports an error.

Comment: Do you want to convert your background based on some condition? For example, If the value is over 50, the background color is black, if the value is blew 50, the background color is red? Can you share your convert code?

Comment: If you use `ResourceDictionary` set a color, it is a static style, If you use `Converter`, it is a dynamic conversion, they are different.

Comment: Yes, there are two different types of themes, one is light and the other is dark. I set a boolean named IsDark in the resource dictionary. When the IsDark is true, it will display the image for the dark theme. When the IsDark set false, it will display the image for the light theme. So I have to get the value of IsDark and set the Source of Image with IValueConverter.

Comment: Or I can only set a string variable in the resource dictionary to store the Source of Image? Although it works, but I have to add so many useless resources like the Source above in the resource dictionary. I just want to add only one for it and convert all values by the IValueConverter.

Comment: In addition, there are so many themes in the App. For example, light green, dark green, light blue, dark blue, and so on. The IsDark does not only control the Source of one Image but also controls the foreground of the Text and so on. It seems the most effective way is just set a boolean IsDark to control all of them.

Comment: I update my answer, you can achieve it by Convert directly. If you have other needs, please open a new thread, keep one thread for one question, thanks.

Comment: Well, that's great! Thank you.